# How do I turn off autocompletion Bracket code editor?

Tags: adobe-brackets

how to disable code autocompletion brackets.io
How do I turn off  autocompletion Bracket code editor?

Answer (score 0):

For now I don't see any preference setting to disable this feature.
Take a look at this below git issue, it might help.

https://github.com/adobe/brackets/issues/4716

Hode it helps,
Cheers